# R algorithm to count days lapsed between phases in a nonlinear process

Tags: r, algorithm, time

It's my first time posting, but I think I've followed all the rules. Let me know if not.

I am trying to create a data frame with information extrapolated from each element (unique ECO #) in a list called changelist. As an example:

`> changelist[560]
$E149914
          ECO               STATUS  Timestamp
25014 E149914 Material Disposition 2017-01-24
25015 E149914             Released 2016-12-20
25016 E149914                  CCB 2016-12-20
25017 E149914            Submitted 2016-12-16
25018 E149914     Technical Review 2016-12-14
25019 E149914              Pending 2016-12-15
25020 E149914                  CCB 2016-12-14
25021 E149914            Submitted 2016-12-13
25022 E149914     Technical Review 2016-12-12
25023 E149914              Pending 2016-12-13
25024 E149914     Technical Review 2016-12-13
25025 E149914              Pending 2016-12-13
25026 E149914                 Hold 2016-12-13
25027 E149914                  CCB 2016-11-30
25028 E149914            Submitted 2016-11-30
25029 E149914     Technical Review 2016-11-30
25030 E149914              Pending 2016-11-24
25031 E149914           Unassigned 2016-10-19`

The resulting data frame (let's call it "data.frame") will have 5 columns:

1. **ECO:** unique ECO #
2. **TRCount:** how many times the ECO has gone under Technical Review
3. **CCBCount:** how many times the ECO has gone under CCB
4. **TRDays:** total number of days spent in Technical Review (cumulative sum of all days spent in each TRCount)
5. **CCBDays:** total number of days spent in CCB (cumulative sum of all days spent in each CCBCount)

This is what I have so far:

```
for (i in 1:length(changelist)){
ECO[i] = as.character(changelist[[i]]$ECO[1])
TRCount[i] = length(which(changelist[[i]]$STATUS == "Technical Review"))
CCBCount[i] = nrow(subset(changelist[[i]], grepl(paste("CCB", collapse="|"), changelist[[i]]$STATUS)))}
```

This gets me:

`> data.frame[560,]
        ECO TRCount CCBCount
560 E149914       4        3`

I am having trouble with TRDays and CCBDays. Every ECO in changelist goes through a similar process (begins in Technical Review, goes to CCB, gets released). However, the way in which this process is executed is not always linear. There are lag periods between each point in the process (called pending/submitted). Sometimes a technical review or CCB can be rejected and the process will start over, or the process will loop a few times at a technical review or CCB before moving onto the next stage. All of these variations can be seen in the example above for ECO149914.

This is how I think the code might be written:

*Start search from the bottom of the data frame*

1. Find first occurrence of "Technical Review" in changelist[[560]]$STATUS. Store the index (a).
2. Search rows above row index (a) for the next occurrence of either "Technical Review" or "CCB" in changelist[[560]]$STATUS. Store the index of this next occurrence (b).
3. The length of time spent in Technical Review is then TRDays = abs(changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[b]-changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[a]).
4. Find the next occurrence of either "Technical Review", "CCB", or "Released" in rows above row index (b) in changelist[[560]]$STATUS. Store the index (c).

   - If changelist[[560]]$STATUS[b] gives "Technical Review", TRDays = TRDays + abs(changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[c]-changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[b])
   - If changelist[[560]]$STATUS[b] gives "CCB", CCBDays = abs(changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[c]-changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[b])
5. Search rows above row index (c) for the next occurrence of "Technical Review", "CCB", or "Released" in changelist[[560]]$STATUS. Store this index as (d).

   - If changelist[[560]]$STATUS[c] gives "Technical Review", TRDays = TRDays + abs(changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[d]-changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[c])
   - If changelist[[560]]$STATUS[c] gives "CCB", CCBDays = CCBDays + abs(changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[d]-changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[c])
   - If changelist[[560]]$STATUS[c] gives "Released", CCBDays = CCBDays + abs(changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[d]-changelist[[560]]$Timestamp[c]) and terminate the loop.
   - If changelist[[560]]$STATUS[c] does not give "Released", repeat step 5.

The issue is I'm not sure that this is the most efficient logic. If it works, I don't know how to translate it into R code. I am looking for suggestions in logic first, and then possible functions/packages in R that will be helpful for translating the logic. Other comments are welcome too.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `data.table` rather than `for` loops to produce the following output:

```
#        ECO           STATUS number_of_times total_days
# 1: E149914              CCB               3     6 days
# 2: E149914 Technical Review               4    14 days
```

I have tried to add comments to the following code to ease understanding, and I suggest you inspect the intermediate objects to understand the logic:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(eco = c("E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", 
"E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", 
"E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", "E149914", 
"E149914", "E149914"), status = c("Unassigned", "Pending", "CCB", 
"Submitted", "Technical Review", "Technical Review", "Submitted", 
"Pending", "Technical Review", "Pending", "Hold", "Technical Review", 
"CCB", "Pending", "Submitted", "Released", "CCB", "Material Disposition"
), timestamp = structure(c(17093, 17129, 17135, 17135, 17135, 
17147, 17148, 17148, 17148, 17148, 17148, 17149, 17149, 17150, 
17151, 17155, 17155, 17190), class = "Date")), .Names = c("ECO", 
"STATUS", "Timestamp"), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = "data.frame", index = structure(integer(0), "`__status`" = c(3L, 
13L, 17L, 11L, 18L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 16L, 4L, 7L, 15L, 5L, 6L, 
9L, 12L, 1L)))
setDT(dt)

# Set Timestamp to Date class and order by Timestamp (ascending)
dt[, Timestamp := as.Date(Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d")]
setorder(dt, Timestamp)

# Count number of rows with these status names
status_names <- c("Technical Review", "CCB")
dt_count <- dt[STATUS %in% status_names,
  .(number_of_times = .N), by = .(ECO, STATUS)]

#        ECO           STATUS number_of_times
# 1: E149914              CCB               3
# 2: E149914 Technical Review               4

# Sum time/days by adding an end day (Timestamp frow row below)
time_break_names <- c(status_names, "Released")
dt_time <- dt[STATUS %in% time_break_names]
dt_time[, end := shift(Timestamp, 1, type = "lead")]
dt_time[, days := end - Timestamp]

#        ECO           STATUS  Timestamp        end    days
# 1: E149914              CCB 2016-11-30 2016-11-30  0 days
# 2: E149914 Technical Review 2016-11-30 2016-12-12 12 days
# 3: E149914 Technical Review 2016-12-12 2016-12-13  1 days
# 4: E149914 Technical Review 2016-12-13 2016-12-14  1 days
# 5: E149914 Technical Review 2016-12-14 2016-12-14  0 days
# 6: E149914              CCB 2016-12-14 2016-12-20  6 days
# 7: E149914         Released 2016-12-20 2016-12-20  0 days
# 8: E149914              CCB 2016-12-20       <NA> NA days

dt_time <- dt_time[STATUS %in% status_names,
  .(total_days = sum(days, na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(ECO, STATUS)]

#        ECO           STATUS total_days
# 1: E149914              CCB     6 days
# 2: E149914 Technical Review    14 days

# Merge counts and time
dt_out <- dt_count[dt_time, on = c("ECO", "STATUS")]
```

Please note that e.g. the first CCB review from 2016-11-30 to 2016-11-30 is counted as 0 days. If you want it to count as 1 day you need to modify this line:

```
dt_time[, days := 1 + end - Timestamp]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The solution for this particular ECO (the 506th on in changelist) is very clear. However, I have a list of 5003 ECOs. How could I generalize what you've written to iterate over each ECO in changelist?

Comment: Start by making a single `data.table` from your list using `dt <- rbindlist(changelist, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`. Then just run the code in the answer.